# Encode Stream From WebCamera

Tags: c#, video-streaming

need an advice, how can I encode stream coming from my webcamera? any C# examples, libraries or codecs?

Comment: What do you mean by "encode"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to 'show' it, you can use Silverlight 4's built-in support

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Capturing-the-Webcam-in-Silverlight-4.aspx

If you want to save it, I'd imagine you're better off using the Expression Encoder SDK and its Live Encoding support via WebcamVideoProfile, although maybe WPF already has something for this

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/expressionencoder/whats-new-in-the-expression-encoder-3-sdk)

Comment: this helped me alot, but I want to use my webcam as datasource, how can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "as datasource"?  For instance, the Expression Encoder SDK supports the webcam as an encoding source as-is - for instance, see the 'Live Encoding' section ("Expression Encoder also supports encoding from live sources such as a webcam.") of this article which includes a code snippet to do so: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714558.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have drivers installed, and then use something like [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I need to live stream my webcam video, directShow doesn't allows me to do it